# REST api not adding right details with POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make my own REST API using express/node.js. I've been following a tutorial one YouTube and I've come to the point where I'm testing out postman POSTing data to an array I've stored called `users`.

Here is my post

```
app.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
   const user = {
      userID: users.length + 1,
      name: req.body.name,
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email
  };
  users.push(user);
  res.send(user);
})
```

Here is my array

```
const users = [{ 
    userID: 1, 
    name: 'Thomas',
    username: 'Tomhass1999',
    email: 'tomhass@yahoo.com'
}, { 
    userID: 2,
    name: 'Bob',
    username: 'Bobina1998',
    email: 'bobiskewl@gmail.com'
}, { 
    userID: 3,
    name: 'Gerald',
    username: 'geraldorivero1965',
    email: 'witch3r3bestgame@gmail.com' 
}];
```

Here is the function to display them.

```
app.get('/api/users/:userID', (req, res) => {
const user = users.find(c => c.userID === parseInt(req.params.userID));
if(!user) // 404
{
    res.status(404).send("The user with the given ID was not found");
}
res.send(user);
})
```

When I use postman I click post, enter `http://localhost:3000/api/users` and it shows me the array and all the information I'd expect. However upon entering this into post man text box

```
{   
    name: 'Grindlebold',
    username: 'Btestest38',
    email: 'estestes2312ewl@gmail.com'
}
```

The output is only

```
{
    "userID": 6
}
```

and upon going into `http://localhost:3000/api/users` on firefox, it shows me the first 3 points in the array and then just:

```
0   
userID  1
name    "Thomas"
username    "Tomhass1999"
email   "tomhass@yahoo.com"
1   
userID  2
name    "Bob"
username    "Bobina1998"
email   "bobiskewl@gmail.com"
2   
userID  3
name    "Gerald"
username    "geraldorivero1965"
email   "witch3r3bestgame@gmail.com"
3   
userID  4
4   
userID  5
5   
userID  6
```

My question is how would I get it to the point where it would save it properly with all the information I need?

```
/*
---
KEY
---
req = request
res = response

GET = get data
POST = submit data


*/


const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());


const users = [
    { 
        userID: 1, 
        name: 'Thomas',
        username: 'Tomhass1999',
        email: 'tomhass@yahoo.com'
    },
    { 
        userID: 2,
        name: 'Bob',
        username: 'Bobina1998',
        email: 'bobiskewl@gmail.com'
    },
    { 
        userID: 3,
        name: 'Gerald',
        username: 'geraldorivero1965',
        email: 'witch3r3bestgame@gmail.com' 
    },
];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

// returns the user list
app.get('/api/users', (req, res) => {
    res.send(users);
})

// adds a user to the user list
app.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
    const user = {
        userID: users.length + 1,
        name: req.body.name,
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email
    };
    users.push(user);
    res.send(user);
})

app.get('/api/users/:userID', (req, res) => {
    const user = users.find(c => c.userID === parseInt(req.params.userID));
    if(!user) // 404
    {
        res.status(404).send("The user with the given ID was not found");
    }
    res.send(user);
})

// PORTS
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}...`))
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `user` and `users` in the `app.post` callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means your express `req.body` is not populated with your request payload! For this, your app should use the `express.json` or `express.urlencoded` middlewares:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false });

...
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help, yeah I've already gotten that. I'll upload the full file to my question

Comment: Also, make sure your POST body in postman is configured to be `raw > JSON ( application/json )` or select `x-www-form-urlencoded` and enter key/values one by one.